# Ionic errors with install after pull or clone

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I always have problems with git, pulls, push, commits, merge AGHH..
I cloned a repository where I am working and when is downloaded,  I run "**npm install**" and show me this message:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/app-version@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/deeplinks@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/facebook@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/google-plus@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/intercom@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.3.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0 requires a peer of firebase@^3.6.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 114 packages and updated 34 packages in 17.482s
```

And I think, that maybe are not installed, but are in **config.xml** but plugin folder doesn't exist. So, I run "**ionic cordova platform add android**" and then creates the folder with all plugins.

When it's finished run "ionic serve" and show this error:

```
Typescript Error
Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
...hub/app/node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts
    storage: () => firebase.storage.Storage;
    delete: () => firebase.Promise<any>;
}
Typescript Error
Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
...ub/app/node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts
```

etc...
How can I fix it?? I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your firebase version, [firebase.Promise was removed in version 4.5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1199) of the firebase SDK. Now you just use a regular Promise. PFB the sample

```
signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.auAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! 
I run "npm uninstall firebase angularfire2 --save", "npm install firebase angularfire2 --save" and change where was deprecated functions and works!!